# MariaDB Insert Ignore JDBC Query -> Lock Wait Time Exceeded

Tags: jdbc, mariadb

I am in the process of testing a MariaDB for query return times (how long different queries take). I have a prototype application that uses C3P0 for concurrency. A producer puts queries on a Queue. A Consumer takes from that Queue and as C3P0 has connections available, it creates a DBProcessor thread that takes the connection, issues the query, processes the results and dies.

The issue I am currently seeing is when I create a DB with a bunch of tables and try to INSERT IGNORE data from another DB... it's a subset of data that I'm taking from an existing DB and inserting into my new DB, I get an error saying "java.sql.SQLException: (conn:2040) Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction". This does not seem to happen when I use a plain INSERT without the ignore part, although that without the ignore it does seem to have primary key issues where there are duplicates in the source DB.

Anyone have any clue as to what could be causing this exception or what I can do to resolve it?

Comment: You could try `conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);` immediately after creating your connection(s) and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I believe it ended up being a concurrency issue. Your suggestion fixed it intermittently. I had INSERT queries relying on tables that were concurrently being constructed and sometimes were not created in time. I sent the INSERTS for the tables that were dependencies for other INSERTS first and it seemed to resolve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Not enough specifics.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a sample of the SQL.